# How to change the placeholder font color for dcc.Input, using Plotly's Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I cannot figure out how to change the placeholder's font color for dcc.Input, Via Plotly's Dash. For this example, I would like to change the placeholder font color to blue.

I have searched through the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/input), but have not been able to find a solution.

Thanks,

Here is what I have tried...

```
    dcc.Input(
               placeholder='Name...',
               type='text',
               value='',
               style={'display': 'inline-block',
                      'background-color': 'white',
                      'border-color': 'white',
                      'color': 'red',
                      'place-holder-color':'blue'

                     }
              )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get help on a different forum, but answering my own question here incase someone else ever struggles with this.

To change the placeholder's font color for dcc.Input, via Plotly's Dash, you need to add this line of code to your projects CSS file..

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: blue; #replace blue with whatever color your want your font to be 
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

Incase, like me, you did not even have a CSS file for your project yet, here is a link to the Dash documentation showing how to add one: [Adding Your Own CSS](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources)

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! You may mark your answer as "accepted answer", so that the question is closed.